# ¿Por que Convert.ToDateTime no puedo convertir string del mes de marzo? ("01-mar-2017")

Tags: c#, asp

De la lectura de una planilla Excel recibo los siguientes datos:

1. "01-mar-2017"
2. "01-ago-2017"
3. "01-jun-2017"
4. "0"

Para validar estos datos yo hago:

(Configuro la Info cultural para tranformar la fecha, ya probé "en-US", "es-ES", "es" y "es-AR")

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-AR");
try
{
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(sFecha, cInfo); //sFecha es alguno de los valores anteriormente mencionados
}
catch
{
//informo que el dato no respeta el formato de fecha
}
```

Con la System.Globalization.CultureInfo "es-AR" Funcionan todos los casos menos para el item 1. "01-mar-2017" (No entiendo por que debería funcionar), la fechas de Marzo no me las convierte, pero si cambio la System.Globalization.CultureInfo a la "en-US" si me convierte las fechas de marzo pero cuando llega una fecha de agosto obvia mente no anda (August = agosto en ingles).

Alguien podría compartir alguna forma en la que pueda validar estas fechas usando el DateTime (Puedo verificar el formato de la cadena y asi comprobarlo analizando cada carácter, pero supongo de debe haber una forma mas amable de hacerlo)

```
DateTime.TryParse
```

DateTime.TryParse no sirve me convierte el "0" en una fecha.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: y el 0 en que deberia convertirse? si tu problema es el cero, porque no lo escapas y listo, porque dijiste que el resto con tryparse andaba...

Comment: Es un "0" pero podría ser cualquier string numérico (ejemplos "1", "2" o "9999999999"), o cualquier Texto, por eso estaba usando el Convert.ToDateTime, porque los números no los convierte. solo los textos de tipo "01-jun-2017" hasta que por alguna razon "01-mar-2017" no me lo convierte.

Comment: @NorbyAriel, ¿El `CultureInfo` viene también en el Excel o cual es el criterio para establecer el `CultureInfo`? - además, si `DateTime.TryParse` te convierte el cero en una fecha, entonces ¿cuál es el problema con obtener una fecha de un número `0`?, y creo que es importante saber: ¿cuál es criterio que usas para establecer si X o Y fecha es una fecha, esperas algún formato?

Comment: El CultureInfo a establecer no es el problema, porque si lo leo desde el Excel en "es-AR" y trato de convertir esa fecha en el mismo CultureInfo este no funciona para una fecha como "01-mar-2017", si el usuario informa un "0" no puedo permitírselo, debe informar una fecha, lo mismo con un texto, si el me informa un "0" y yo lo convierto a una fecha y paso este dato a quien lo solicita, estoy pasando un dato erroneo, no es una fecha es un "0", el formato es "dd-mmm-aaaa", según lo pacta el usuario.

Comment: Entiendo que muchos ven soluciones fáciles a este problema, pero el problema es que yo no puedo tomar las decisiones, yo ni permitiría que los datos se carguen en un Excel, sino en un ABM que valide los datos, pero eso no lo decido yo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es un poco raro que no te funcione de la manera que lo estas realizando, la opción que pudiera ayudarte es definir en el culture info la abreviación de los meses de manera personalizada, te dejo un ejemplo que espero resuelva tu problema

```
var x = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
x.FullDateTimePattern = "dd/M/yyy";
x.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new string[] { "ene", "feb", "mar", "abr", "may", "jun", "jul", "ago", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dic","" };
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-AR");
cInfo.DateTimeFormat = x;

        try
        {
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(sFecha.ToUpper(), cInfo); //sFecha es alguno de los valores anteriormente mencionados
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //informo que el dato no respeta el formato de fecha
        }
```

Comment: Esta tambien es una opción interesante. Gracias por tu aportación.

Comment: Funciono todo de una Mil Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

el problema es que no pasas el formato actual de la fecha que estas convirtiendo.

Espero esto te ayude. Un saludo

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] dateValues = { "01-mar-2017" ,"01-ago-2017", "01-jun-2017" ,"0"};

    var format = "dd-MMM-yyyy";

    foreach (var dateValue in dateValues)
    {
        ValidarFechas(dateValue, format);
    }

    Console.Read();
}


public static void ValidarFechas(string sFecha, string format)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(sFecha, format, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out var parsedDate))
        Console.WriteLine("convertido '{0}' a {1:d}.", sFecha, parsedDate);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("no se puede convertir '{0}' a fecha.", sFecha);
}
```

Salida de consola:

```
convertido '01-mar-2017' a 01/03/2017.
convertido '01-ago-2017' a 01/08/2017.
convertido '01-jun-2017' a 01/06/2017.
no se puede convertir '0' a fecha.
```

Comment: Tienes razón en tu respuesta,pero te falta añadir el formato necesario. Añade el código de las llamadas al método para poder verlo.

Comment: Después de obtener la fecha, @NorbyAriel podrá pasar a la cultura que el quiera.

Comment: No me entiendes @Manux. No es la cultura, para que tu respuesta sea completa debes añadir que le estás pasando en `format` para que `TryParseExact` convierta correctamente `'01-mar-2017'` a `01/03/2017`.

Comment: Ahora si está perfecto, faltaba el `dd-MMM-yyyy`. +1 :)

Comment: Gracias, TAMBIÉN FUNCIONA!!